# Обрезка запроса у URL в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Необходимо обрезать запрос из URL. Пользователя после некоторого действия автоматически перенаправляет на страницу для примера https://test.ru/end/?i=qwerty. Необходимо отлавливать страницу и обрубать запрос (все что после ? и его тоже) и выводить для пользователя https://test.ru/end/.
Данный запрос возник из за проблемы, что в некоторых случаях браузер не может интерпретировать запрос так как url слишком большой и выдает вместо данной страницы - страницу 404.

Попытался сделать таким образом

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
if((stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'end') === true) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    wp_redirect(home_url(/end/));
    exit;
  }
});
```

что делаю не так?

Comment: Так у вас тут бесконечный редирект.  Проверьте, что есть запрос `? ` и `end`, и только в этом случае делайте редирект.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, изменил немного условие. Но по прежнему при переходе по ссылке с запросом он не отрубается, а остается.

Comment: Так не должно быть. Проверьте этот код без плагинов на стандартной пустой теме.

Comment: Ну и синтаксис, конечно, неправильный `wp_redirect( home_url( '/end/' ) );` строка не в кавычках

Comment: Проверил на пустой теме не работает. Синтаксис в порядке, это здесь косячно написал. Есть какой то другой способ отслеживания url, по которым переходит пользователь?

Comment: Все заработало, спасибо за помощь. Заработало само собой, видимо сервер закэшировался.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
  if((stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'end') === true) && 
    !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    wp_redirect( home_url('/end/') );
    exit;
  }
});
```